# Generate Database from NHibernate config files

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Is it possible to generate the database tables and c# classes from NHibernate config files?  Afterwards, is it possible to change the config files and update the tables and config files non-destructively?

Do you recommend any tools to do this?  (preferably free...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned by Joachim, it's the "hbm2ddl.auto" setting that you're looking for.

You can set it by code like this:

```
var cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
cfg.SetProperty("hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
cfg.Configure();
```

And you can also set it in your App.config file:

```
    <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to generate the database tables and C# classes from the NHibernate config files. Let me explain with this example here .

1 : Address.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hibernate-mapping
    xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.0"
    default-cascade="none">

    <class
        name="Your.Domain.AddressImpl, Your.Domain"
        table="[ADDRESS]"
        dynamic-insert="true"
        dynamic-update="true"
        lazy="true">

        <id name="Id" type="long" unsaved-value="0">
            <column name="ID" sql-type="NUMERIC(19,0)"/>
            <generator class="native">            </generator>
        </id>



        <property name="Address1" type="string">
            <column name="ADDRESS1" not-null="true" unique="false" sql-type="VARCHAR(100)"/>
        </property>

        <property name="Address2" type="string">
            <column name="ADDRESS2" not-null="true" unique="false" sql-type="VARCHAR(100)"/>
        </property>

        <property name="City" type="string">
            <column name="CITY" not-null="true" unique="false" sql-type="VARCHAR(100)"/>
        </property>

        <property name="State" type="string">
            <column name="STATE" not-null="true" unique="false" sql-type="VARCHAR(100)"/>
        </property>

        <property name="Zipcode" type="string">
            <column name="ZIPCODE" not-null="true" unique="false" sql-type="VARCHAR(100)"/>
        </property>




    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Step 2 : 
Just by the looking at the configuration file , you Address object siply looks like the following

```
using System;

namespace Your.Domain
{

    public partial class Address
    {



        #region Attributes and Associations

        private string _address1;
        private string _address2;
        private string _city;
        private long _id;
        private string _state;
        private string _zipcode;

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string Address1
        {
            get { return _address1; }
            set { this._address1 = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string Address2
        {
            get { return _address2; }
            set { this._address2 = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string City
        {
            get { return _city; }
            set { this._city = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public virtual long Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { this._id = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string State
        {
            get { return _state; }
            set { this._state = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string Zipcode
        {
            get { return _zipcode; }
            set { this._zipcode = value; }
        }


        #endregion 
    }
}
```

Step 3 : And again if you look at the "Column" name property and its data type that is actually refers to the Actual backend database table called "Address".

There are also huge amount of tools that help you to generate all these artifacts for you based on different input such as UML, Or Actual Database schema etc.

Answer (score 2):

check out the "hbm2ddl.auto" setting (in configuration or NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration ). with "create" you can recreate the whole database schema from your mappings and "update" setting should just update your schema.