# Is it possible to create a database using NHibernate?

Tags: database, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using NHibernate with FluentNHibernate for my DAL. I am also using `SchemaExport` and `SchemaUpdate` to create and update my database schema.

My problem is that the schema operations all require the database to exist before they will work. I want to programmatically create my database and update the schema as there may be multiple databases and the creating of the database is not only a once-off operation.

I know I can do this manually by executing a create database command on a connection to the master database, but this feels wrong considering that I otherwise use NHibernate for all my database interactions. As an aside, I use a SQLite inmemory database for my unit tests so any sql I write will then have to know which database I'm using.

Is there any way to get NHibernate to create my database for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [RhinoCommons](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Commons.ashx). Under Rhino.Commons.ForTesting, in [UnitOfWorkTestContextDbStrategy.cs](https://rhino-tools.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/rhino-tools/trunk/commons/Rhino.Commons.NHibernate/ForTesting/UnitOfWorkTestContextDbStrategy.cs), [Ayende](http://ayende.com/blog/) has done some routine there that  creates databases.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use this, it's not really what I wanted (NHibernate doing the work) but it's pretty cool. I was surprised to see a hardcoded "(local)" db server reference :-)

Answer (score 12):

I think that creating db with NHibernate is nice, if you start to develop application with domain model. I mean - it gives an insight how your db should look. But in general - sql scripts should be used.

I heard that some developers uses NHibernate db generation for integration tests, they create lightweight sqlite db on fly.

How to generate db with NHibernate? This is how i do that:

```
 public static void InitSessionFactory()
    {
        var connectionString =
            ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"]
                .ConnectionString;

        var cfgFromXml = new Configuration();
        cfgFromXml.Configure();

        var cfg = Fluently.Configure(cfgFromXml)
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
                          .ConnectionString(x => x.Is(connectionString))
                          .UseReflectionOptimizer())
            .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings
                               .AddFromAssemblyOf<NHibernateBootstrapper>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema);


        ObjectFactory.Inject(cfg.BuildSessionFactory());
    }

    private static void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
    {
        //Creates database structure
        //new SchemaExport(config)
        //   .Create(false, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

No, NHibernate will not create the database for you. Creating databases is something you usually don't want do be done on the fly. It needs many configuration parameters and this is very database specific, even database version specific.

For our product, I wrote a class that sets up the database. It is used for the installer, the integration tests and the database maintenance tool.

- NHibernate creates the connection using its configuration.
- my own implementation creates the database. There are different implementations for different dialects.
- NH creates the tables and other database objects
- Installer classes create initial data

There is also a special case, where a customer doesn't want to grant the right to create databases. Then we expect him to do it and skip this part.

Comment: Creating a SqlCe database takes just one line of code: new SqlCeEngine( string.Format("Data Source='{0}';", path) ).CreateDatabase();

Comment: Yes, creating a a sql server database using default configurations is not more complicated. But this is not the point. NH doesn't do it because it would make much sense.

Comment: This is not exactly true anymore. With NH3 you can use hbm2ddl as part of the NHibernate.Tool namespace

Comment: @burnt_hand: interesting. But I can't find any kind of "create database" in that code neither. How is the database created then?

Comment: There is [SchemaExport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022894/nhibernate-schemaexport-and-configure-catch-22/1022915#1022915) which can be used. I'm not sure how destructive it is in regards to existing data/structure as I haven't used it yet. Will do tonight though for my pet project

Comment: But this doesn't create the database, as far as I can see. It just creates the schema (tables, indexes etc.).

Answer (score 5):

We use SchemaExport to provide a schema and a Nant task to drop and recreate the database.  Another Nant task runs the schema export and dataloading code which exists in the form of an integration test run by the nunit task. There is a [sample here](http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/source/browse/trunk/nant.build).

Comment: This code seems to have moved to http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4755c1386bff#nant.build

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you can indeed use SchemaExport as you mention, but I see NHibernate primarely as a way to bridge the gap between OO domain model and a relational persistence storage.
That is, for me NHibernate's purpose is to persist and retrieve entities in my domain model.

When you want to do schema updates, imho, you should not use NHibernate (if possible at all), since that's not the purpose of NHibernate; there is a 'domain specific language' called SQL :) which is good at doing those things.

In order to create my database, and update my database-schema, I use [Migrator.NET](https://github.com/migratordotnet/Migrator.NET), which is a framework which lets you write C# classes in where you specify what needs to be done (create a table, add a column, etc...).
The advantage of this, is that Migrator.NET also supports multiple DBMS'es, so you do not end up writing DB-specific SQL code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a look at Migrator.Net, looks pretty cool, though it doesn't solve my problem of actually creating the database.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for this myself as I've seen it done in java - similiar question here: [Generate Database from NHibernate config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432118/generate-database-from-nhibernate-config-files/)

Comment: This question is about creating the database, not the tables.